# jquery mobile get previous page URL

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to find the previous page url in Jquery Mobile?

I used **data.prevPage.attr("href")** but its not working.

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pagechange` event handler receives a second argument `fromPage` from which you can extract the URL of the page you are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You might use plain JavaScript and try it with:

```
document.referrer
```

This variable will contain the previous page url if there is one.

Comment: i don't want to use javascript. Jquery will also solve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I got an easy way of going back to the previous page:

**history.back()**

or **history.go(-1)**

This works fine for me !!

Thanks for the help.